# backbonejs model.save method --post request params become null on the server side

Tags: spring, tomcat, post, backbone.js

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here???

In bankbonejs, I am trying to make a POST request. Here is my code: Im using tomcat server.

```
 $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
      var o = {};
      var a = this.serializeArray();
      $.each(a, function() {
          if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
              if (!o[this.name].push) {
                  o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
              }
              o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
          } else {
              o[this.name] = this.value || '';
          }
      });
      return o;
    };
saveDetails: function (ev) {
            var abcDetails= $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
            var abc= new ABC();
            bank.save(abcDetails, {
              success: function (abc) {
                router.navigate('', {trigger:true});
              }
            });
            return false;
          }
```

Call goes to the server side (Tomcat) but the post request params are coming as null. I have checked `var abcDetails` just before requesting the `save` has the values populated correctly. Also, checked by sending post request thru PostMaster to make sure that values are passed from the client side correctly. However, on the server side these posted request params are null. I am some how stuck here.vAppreciate help in this regard.

Server Side

.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/postedValues" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String getpostedValues(  HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
            String _id = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(request.getParameter("id"));
            String col1= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(request.getParameter("col1"));
            String col2= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(request.getParameter("col2"));
```

Also,
`Enumeration paramaterNames = request.getParameterNames();
while(paramaterNames.hasMoreElements() ) {
               System.out.println(paramaterNames.nextElement());
        }`--> observation:does not go inside the while loop

Comment: `var abcDetails= seralized obj` this is not even valid javascript. What does this object look like?

Comment: sorry for not explaining that ...serlized obj I used to mention what i was doing to get abcDetails object.. copied the code above